# What file should be the DirectoryIndex in Apache to properly serve Munin graphs?

Tags: munin, directoryindex

This is probably going to be one of those *of course!* answers, but I've spent all night looking up tutorials and FAQs on Munin and can't seem to find the answer.

I have Munin installed, and I'm trying to serve the page that shows the graphs using Apache. My /etc/munin/munin.conf looks like this:

```
 dbdir   /var/lib/munin
 htmldir /var/www/html/munin
 logdir  /var/log/munin
 rundir  /var/run/munin

 tmpldir        /etc/munin/templates


 [localhost]
   address 127.0.0.1
   use_node_name yes
```

As you can see, the HTMLdir is set to /var/www/html/munin. In that directory, I have the following files:

[image]

I'm trying to use apache to serve `status.*mydomain*.com` as the dashboard with all of the Munin graphs. My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has a virtual host that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName status.*mydomain*.com
  DirectoryIndex ###WTF IS THIS????
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/munin
</VirtualHost>

<directory /var/www/html/munin/>
        AllowOverride None
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
#        DirectoryIndex index.cgi
        AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin.passwd
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "Munin stats"
        require valid-user
</directory>
```

My problem is, I don't know what the `DirectoryIndex` needs to be. The only file I see that looks like something Apache would know how to serve is `definitions.html` and I tried doing that but that page doesn't have any graphs. Every tutorial I've read glosses over this detail, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to be by default.

PS: If it helps, I've checked the cron logs and yes, I know that Munin is running every 5 minutes updating the graphs. I just don't know how to serve them properly! Thanks!!

**Edit:** .htaccess looks like the default Munin one:

```
# This file can be used as a .htaccess file, or a part of your apache
# config file.
#
# For the .htaccess file option to work the munin www directory
# (/var/www/html/munin) must have "AllowOverride all" or something close
# to that set.
#
# As a config file enclose it in <directory> like so:
# 
# <directory /var/www/html/munin>

AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
AuthName "Munin"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

# This next part requires mod_expires to be enabled.
#
# We could use <IfModule mod_expires> around here, but I want it to be
# as evident as possible that you either have to load mod_expires _or_
# you coment out/remove these lines.

# Set the default expiery time for files 5 minutes 10 seconds from
# their creation (modification) time.  There are probably new files by
# that time.

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault M310

# </directory>
```

Comment: What is in the .htaccess file?

Comment: DirectoryIndex is the directive to set which files are the index files. like index.htm or index.php on linux, index.asp or default.asp on windows. if it can find one of these files in the directory it will show that file as your webpage, if it cant find any of those files it will show a listing of files in the dir.

Answer (score 2):

`DirectoryIndex` should be `index.html`. Once you start `munin-node` (or run `/usr/bin/munin-cron`) it will be auto generated.